# get values of select option in angular 4+

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Hi I have a question how to get the values from list in a select option.

I have this array

```
{
    "C_ID": "Item044",
    "Descripcion": "Item 1", 
    "ID": "044"
},
{
    "C_ID": "Item045",
    "Descripcion": "Item 2 ,
    "ID": "045"
},
{
    "C_ID": "Item046",
    "Descripcion": "Item 4",
    "ID": "046"
},
{
    "C_ID": "Item047",
    "Descripcion": "Item 5",
    "ID": "047"
},
```

and I get this values in a select option with NgFor but I need when selected for example Item 1 get the ID and C_ID in a input text automatic

Answer (score -1):

> and I get this values in a select option with NgFor but I need when selected for example Item 1 get the ID and C_ID in a input text automatic

Wire an ng model to the select input. And then wire the backed field to the input. Now when the select changes the input text should change.

Comment: Ok I have my model with the all values for example Id:string, name:string and in the component html I use <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Clave" [(ngModel)]="postPercepcion.Clave" value="{{postPercepcion.Clave}}">. Can you give a more specific example